# How to extract numbers from strings on ALL the columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, extract

Using `str.extract()` to extract numbers from strings works (see below), but it's time-consuming when I have to repeat this on 30+ columns.

Originally like this:

```
yyyy
2014    110.7438016528926\K
2015    103.7533512064343\O
2016    111.6531165311653\L
2017                  nan\L
2018                  nan\E
Name: dips_cert_earning_premium_weekly, dtype: object
```

Then I wrote these codes:

```
df['dips_cert_earning_premium_weekly'] = df['dips_cert_earning_premium_weekly'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)').astype(float)
```

Output:

```
yyyy
2014    110.743802
2015    103.753351
2016    111.653117
2017           NaN
2018           NaN
Name: dips_cert_earning_premium_weekly, dtype: float64
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/parse/ try this, it may help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how your whole dataset looks like or what you mean by slow: is it taking minutes? seconds? hours?. However, if it's possible you could try an approach not using regexp. For instance:

```
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\"
def remove_letters(x):
    try:
        return float(x.strip(letters))
    except:
        return None

df['dips_cert_earning_premium_weekly'] = list(map(remove_letters,  df['dips_cert_earning_premium_weekly']))
```

If the dataset only has one column with 31 rows, your version takes 0.0008417534828186036 seconds while the version I propose takes 0.0003292644023895264 seconds so it's a slight difference but it's worth trying. (I calculated this times by taking the times for N=1000 runs and then I took the average of all times)

Otherwise, try to profile your code to see where the bottleneck is and try different implementations until you find the fastest one.

**Edit:**

To fully answer the question with the new data: To iterate over the dataframe and apply this to each column, you can try the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
for (columnName, columnData) in df.iteritems():
   df[columnName] = list(map(remove_letters,  df[columnName])) # This is the same line from before. Only difference is that we are applying it to all columns.
```

Comment: Hi Roxy, thanks for the reply. Here slow means that I have to repeat the same long codes: df=df.str.extract().astype(float) 30+ times because I have 30+ columns that have the same problem. So I'm looking for an alternative way to get the same outcome by using neat and efficient codes. I tried yours and it was quicker and more readable. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Great! If I understood correctly, the problem is also not to repeat the same code several times for each column. You can check this article on how to iterate each column with `iteritems` https://thispointer.com/pandas-loop-or-iterate-over-all-or-certain-columns-of-a-dataframe/ :)

Comment: Forgive me being a newbie to python, I had a look at the website and tried to combine your codes and ```iteritems()``` together but still not quite sure how to do iteration.

Comment: No worries! I will edit the answer with an example on how to do this. Because the code formatting is not great in the comments.

Comment: Hi Roxy, I finally sorted it out now. I've updated the question again. Thank you so much for your support!!

Comment: Great, glad that you figured it out :)